# Can I call a function by inputting a string?

Tags: python, function, dictionary, call

I want to make a function that can be called when the text input is equal to a command.

```
from os import system
from time import sleep
import ctypes

ctypes.windll.kernel32.SetConsoleTitleW('SimpleChat')

print('Hi, welcome to my basic chat engine!')

sleep(5)

system('cls')

username = input('Enter a username: ')

ctypes.windll.kernel32.SetConsoleTitleW('SimpleChat - ' + username)

system('cls')

def commands (command):
    commandlist = ['/help','/clear', '/commands']
    commanddict = {'/help' : 'help', '/clear' : 'clear', '/commands' : 'commands'}
    for possibility in commandlist:
        if command == possibilty:
            commanddict[possibility]()
            break 

def textInput (text):
    if text[0] == '/':
        commands(text)
```

Does line 24 work to call a function? The way I am imagining it will work is that it will find the entry for the key 'possibility', and then call that as a function, but I am not sure.

If the previous code does not work, what would?

Comment: If you have functions `help`, `clear`, and `commands` in scope, you can just stick them in the dictionaries: `{"/help": help, "/clear": clear}` and call them like you do already. No point in keeping two lists though: `if command not in commanddict: print("no such command")`

Comment: In command dict values should be actual `help` funcction (`help`, `clear`, `commands` and so in - without parenthesis). And yes, it would work. `commanddict[possibility]` resolves to function object, which may be called by appending `()`. So, besides creating commanddict, your code is perfectly fine.

Comment: _"Does line 24 work to call a function?"_ Does it work when you run it?

Comment: @ Colonel Thirty Two: Thank you, I did not realize that 'in' could be used that way. Also, the way you are explaining, the part that shows 'help' without quotation marks calls it as a function, no? Because of this, would i need to make a function for each command?

Comment: @Kevin, I have not yet implemented the commands as I am not sure how i want to do so, and therefore cannot test it.

Comment: doing `def help(): print("This is where the help text will go once I think of it")` would be sufficient for testing.

Comment: Good timing on that, I had literally just added that when you commented. And yes, it does work now.

Comment: Albeit edited to be cleaner

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose there's a function called `help`, `clear`,... in your code like this.

```
def help():
    print("help!")
```

Then, the below `commands` function will do what you want. 
Note that function can be used as value of dictionary in Python.

```
def commands (command):
    command_dict = {'/help' : help, '/clear' : clear, '/commands' : commands}
    func = command_dict.get(command)

    if func is not None:
        func()
    else:
        print("I don't have such a command: %s" % command)
```

I guess `'/commands'`'s value(`command` function)  in `command_dict` should be changed to another function. The program will crash if you type 'commands'.